# Django Multi Table Inheritance and Preserving Child and Child History

Tags: postgresql, database-design, inheritance, django

Place can have many different one to one fields, that’s why it can have bookstore, restaurant, and hardware store. But can the same place be both a bookstore and a restaurant at the same time? Now if the bank and restaurant tables don't have the same pk as place, I would think the answer is yes. But I also know that unless you put parent_link=True on it, erasing the child row automatically deletes the parent row.

My use case is to preserve the history of Restaurant despite it’s having now become a Bookstore, and if a Restaurant is simultaneously a Bookstore, to be able to keep both places in my db.   Is the best way to do this with a fk to each of the bookstores, restaurants and hardware stores instead of either a OneToOne or multi table inheritance? Or is there some other way I’m not aware of? This has to be a solved problem, but so far I haven't found it. I'm currently looking at NFL databases because players can be on more than one team, (albeit not at the same time), and they have a recorded history of their team and individual stats - to see if I can hack those into what I want.

I'm even willing to consider an ArrayField or Hstore. I'm on Postgres 9.4 and trying to maintain 3NF. All wisdom accepted. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you have a look at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37199310/70191).

Use `deletion.Collector` with manual collection:

```
from django.db.models import deletion

collector = deletion.Collector(using=minor._state.db)
collector.add([minor])
collector.delete()
```